# How do I change the number on the end of a animated render?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I would like to change the amount of numbers at the end of my animation, separated by BMP images. For example, change 0001 to 001, ect. Thank you! I'm using Internal Render on 2.79.

Answer (score 0):

Check [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/output/output.html#output-panel). Or do [some research before posting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46062/how-to-keep-blender-from-adding-frame-numbers-to-output-filename).

Comment: I couldn't find anything about it when I searched. Please don't be rude.