# world_to_camera_view() returns wrong vertex coordinates

Tags: python, vertices, coordinates

I'm trying to get 2D pixel coordinates (i.e. with respect to the rendered image) of the outline of some spheres I have in my scene. Ultimately, I would like to obtain a segmentation mask for the object, pretty much like the one that images in the [COCO dataset](http://cocodataset.org/#home) have.

I'm not even sure I'm doing the right thing here, since I'm currently looking for the vertices' coordinates, but here's the code I'm using at the moment:

```py
import numpy as np
import bpy_extras
import bpy

BALLS = 'Balls'
CAMERA = 'Camera'

scene = bpy.context.scene

render_scale = scene.render.resolution_percentage / 100

# Get width and height of the rendered image
render_width  = int(
    scene.render.resolution_x * render_scale
)
render_height = int(
    scene.render.resolution_y * render_scale
)

balls = bpy.data.collections[BALLS].all_objects

# This dictionary maps ball names to a list of vertex coordinates
ball_names = [ball.name for ball in balls]
ball_boundaries = dict(
    zip(ball_names, [[] for _ in range(len(balls))])
)

camera = bpy.data.objects[CAMERA]
for ball in balls:

    for vertex in ball.data.vertices:

        # Get vertex coordinates in world space
        vertex_coords = ball.matrix_world @ vertex.co

        # Get vertex coordinates in camera space
        vertex_camera_view_coords = bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view(
            scene, 
            camera, 
            vertex_coords
        )

        ball_boundaries[ball.name].append((
            vertex_camera_view_coords.x * render_width,
            vertex_camera_view_coords.y * render_height
        ))

    print(f'{ball.name}: {ball_boundaries[ball.name]}')
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_extras.object_utils.html#bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view) for `world_to_camera_view()`, the function is supposed to return coordinates in the [0, 1] range ((0, 0) being the bottom left corner of the rendered image and (1, 1) being the top right corner), though values outside that range can also be returned, which I suppose would intimate that the object is outside of the camera's view.

In fact, the coordinates returned by `world_to_camera_view()` for the balls' vertices are outside that range even though they are within the camera's scope, as witnessed by this image:
[image]
While that was the camera view in "Rendered" mode, here's the same but in "Solid" mode:
[image]

Actually, no ball is within the camera's scope in this case, but I would assume that the "Rendered" view is what matters, right? Because if I try to render the scene, the image I get is what the camera sees in "Render" mode, not in "Solid" mode. In any case - and this is not the main question - do you know why the camera view in "Rendered" mode is different than that in "Solid" mode?

Looking once more at the documentation for `world_to_camera_view()`, I noticed that the function *"Takes shift-x/y, lens angle and sensor size into account as well as perspective/ortho projections."*, although it doesn't say what that implies. Looking at the [source code](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/modules/bpy_extras/object_utils.py$230) didn't help, either (unless I failed to understand what it does). Truth be told, I actually modified the camera's sensor size and field of view (as you can probably tell by the distortion present in the image), though I don't know how to take such modifications into account so that `world_to_camera_view()` returns coordinates in the [0, 1] range as expected. Here are the parameters I've set for the camera:

[image]

Comment: `world_to_camera_view` doesn't work on the render data, it works on the direct data you see in the 3D view, so if an object is outside the camera in 3D space (regardless of the render) that's the data `world_to_camera_view` uses. Essentially, it doesn't work with 'Panoramic' camera types. I don't know of a workaround otherwise I would add this as an answer.

Comment: This is also why the 3D view differs so much from the render, because the 3D view cannot show the 'Fisheye Equisolid' distortions in realtime.

Comment: @RayMairlot That's some very useful information, thanks

Comment: To your question "why the camera view in "Rendered" mode is different than that in "Solid" mode", this is due to the fact that you are using panoramic camera which has non linear space which cannot be rendered in Solid mode (or Eevee) which is rasterized. It can only be rendered in ray tracing mode.

Comment: The answer in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165777/how-to-find-all-image-coordinates-of-rendered-object is perfect for creating images like the ones in the COCO dataset. If you still need the coordinates you could write a python script that returns the coordinates of all pixel having a specific color.