# Get pixel coordinates of an object's surface without rendering

Tags: rendering, camera

How do I get pixel coordinates (in the rendered image) of an object's surface **without** rendering the scene?

A similar problem would be getting pixel coordinates of an object's vertices, which you can easily achieve by looping over the object's vertices, get their coordinates in world space, then finally use `bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view()` to convert them to pixel coordinates **without** actually rendering the scene.

So, how do I get pixel coordinates of an object's entire surface (not just its vertices) without rendering the scene?

Comment: I think you can't really get away from rendering a super simplified version, here is a very similar question to yours: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165777/how-to-find-all-image-coordinates-of-rendered-object/166221#166221

Comment: Alright, then I have another question: can you at least get pixel coordinates of an object's surface when it's covered by another object?

Comment: You should Tag with @ WhatAMesh if you want people to get notified. Yes, you can just add a tiny bit of code that only makes one object at a time visible