# KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "View Layer" not found'

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

As I tried to reproduce this code:
[How to find all image coordinates of rendered object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165777/how-to-find-all-image-coordinates-of-rendered-object/253478#253478)

I encountered an error:

```
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "View Layer" not found'
```

All objects are in a collection, so was is the problem?

Comment: `bpy.context.scene.view_layers['ViewLayer'].use_pass_object_index = True` or `bpy.context.view_layer.use_pass_object_index = True` should do...?

Comment: ... updated the code for 2.8+: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/166221/